# how do you remove specific table row lines in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried doing this by creating a class called no-line. didn't work. if I take out .no-line then there will be no lines on the table. 
I just want to remove specific lines from a specific row. how can I do that?

```
.table thead > tr > th, 
        .table tbody > tr > th, 
        .table tfoot > tr > th, 
        .table thead > tr > td, 
        .table tbody > tr > td, 
        .table tfoot > tr > td.no-line {
     border-top: none !important; 
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Try using :nth-child() ,  if you put exactly which lines and which fields you want to show and hide I could try to give you a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

turned off the rows lines

```
.table thead > tr > th, 
        .table tbody > tr > th, 
        .table tfoot > tr > th, 
        .table thead > tr > td, 
        .table tbody > tr > td, 
        .table tfoot > tr > td {
     border-top: none !important; 
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

and then added by own lines with
 an <hr/> where I wanted lines with:




  hr {
    border: none !important;
    height: 2px !important;
    /* Set the hr color */
    color: #333 !important; /* old IE */
    background-color: #333 !important; /* Modern Browsers */
}
```